# Is there any other approach to mock this method call in constructor

Tags: java, spring, mocking, mockito

I have this class:
**SqssReadderApp**:

```
 @Autowired
    private Source source;
    @Autowired
    private AWSProperties awsProperties;
    @Autowired
    private AuditRepository auditRepository;
    private AmazonSQS sqs;

    @Autowired
    public SqssreaderApplication(AWSConfig awsConfig) {
        this.sqs = awsConfig.generateSQS();
    }
```

It is calling a method generateSQS() from its constructor. The SQS is generated by invoking a static method. 
Here is the relevant class containing the method:

```
   @Autowired
    private AWSProperties awsProperties;

    @Bean
    AmazonSQS generateSQS() {
        return AmazonSQSClientBuilder.standard()
                .withRegion(awsProperties.getQueueRegion())
                .build();
    }
```

Now, in my test class, I'm trying to mock this generateSQS() method call by injecting a mockAwsConfig. 
I think there are two approches to inject the mockSqs instance in the SqssReaderApplication.

Approach 1: 
 I inject the mockAwsConfig into the constructor and initialize it with this rule:

```
when(mockAwsConfig.generateSQS()).thenReturn(mockSQS);
SqssReaderApplication app = new SqssReaderApplication(mockAwsConfig);
```

problem:
    All the remianing (@Autowired) entities remain null.

Approach 2: 
    I @Autowired the SqssReaderApplication, all the other fields are mocked, but the sqs instance in the SqssReaderApplication remain null.

```
**TestClass**:

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-test.properties")
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {SqssreaderApplication.class,
        DefaultFrameworkSupport.class, AWSConfig.class, AuditRepository.class, FileProcessAuditLog.class})
public class SqssreaderApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private Source source;

    @MockBean
    AuditRepository auditRepository;
    @Mock
    private AmazonSQSClient amazonSQS;
    @Mock
    private AWSConfig awsConfig;

    @InjectMocks
    private SqssreaderApplication app;
    @Mock
    private AWSProperties awsProperties;

    @Before
    public void setup(){
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        when(awsConfig.generateSQS()).thenReturn(amazonSQS);
        app = new SqssreaderApplication(awsConfig);
    }
```

I have seen other answers too, but they don't work in this scenario.
What could be other approach to this problem? How should I inject the mocks in the SqssReaderApp, preferably without using PowerMock or modifying the source code?

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing two ways of dependency injection (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection#Three_types_of_dependency_injection). You should create proper constructor and only this construstor should be @Autowired.
Your class should look something like:

```
private Source source;
private AWSProperties awsProperties;
private AuditRepository auditRepository;
private AmazonSQS sqs;

@Autowired
public SqssreaderApplication(Source source, AWSProperties awsProperties, AuditRepository auditRepository, AWSConfig awsConfig) {
    this.sqs = awsConfig.generateSQS();
```

Then in your test you can modify your #1 Approach and add all required mocks via constructor.
Little offtop: You are using AWSProperties both in AWSConfig and SqssreaderApplication classes. Check if you really need it in SqssreaderApplication.

Answer (score 1):

`AmazonSQS` is also a spring bean which can be injected with `@Autowired`. So you can change the constructor from

```
@Autowired
public SqssReadderApp(AWSConfig awsConfig) {
    this.sqs = awsConfig.generateSQS();
}
```

to

```
@Autowired
public SqssReadderApp(AmazonSQS sqs) {
    this.sqs = sqs;
}
```

Now you can inject your mocked instance into the constructor.

You should also consider to resolve this mix of field injection and constructor injection. I recommend constructor injection which makes testing a lot easier.

```
public class SqssReadderApp {

    @Autowired
    public SqssReadderApp(Source source, AWSProperties awsProperties, AuditRepository auditRepository, AmazonSQS sqs) {
        //
    }
}
```

See also [why field injection is evil](http://olivergierke.de/2013/11/why-field-injection-is-evil/).